# clarification of Python regular expression

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am a little confused on how regular expressions and `sub` works in Python.
I have this example:

```
nw = "  textttt    "
nw = re.sub(r'\s+(textttt)\s+', r'\1 ', nw)
```

The value in `nw` will be `nw = "textttt "`.
However if I have:

```
nw = "  textttt    "
nw = re.sub(r'\s(textttt)\s', r'\1 ', nw)
```

The value of `nw` will be `nw = "  textttt       "`.
Can someone please explain how the first and second results are generated and why they are different?

Comment: Apart from the use of modifiers in regex, your regex works entirely as expected.

Comment: Can you please explain why the whitespaces are removed from `nw`?

Comment: I'm not sure what is confusion here.  In the first case, the pattern matches all the whitespace surrounding `textttt` and the replacement is the backreference followed by a single space.  In the second case, the pattern matches a single whitespace before & after the specified text and accordingly replaced.

Comment: The `+` after `\s` matches one or more spaces. This has the effect of matching all the whitespace that precedes and succeeds "textttt", but since `\s` isn't in the capture group, it's gone after the replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, let's replace spaces with digits:

```
import re
nw = "01textttt2345"

xx = re.sub(r'\d+(textttt)\d+', r'\1 ', nw)
print '[%s]' % xx  # [textttt ]

xx = re.sub(r'\d(textttt)\d', r'\1 ', nw)
print '[%s]' % xx  # [0textttt 345]
```

The first expression finds `01textttt2345` and replaces this with the value of the group(=`textttt`) plus a space. The second one finds only `1textttt2` and replaces that with `textttt`, leaving the rest of the string untouched.

Comment: Thanks, it is a great answer and clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
\\s - works for single whitespace character
\\s+ - works for sequence of one or more whitespace characters.
```

Comment: Thank, but ho the whitespaces are removed?